# Rails: autopopulate form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Currently I am working with two models, `teachers` and `users`.

I am allowing group teachers to register (using devise) their own users, who will be associated with those teacher by a teacher_id. For example, group members with teacher Id's of 1 will all be part of leader 1's cohort.

**Update:** My original question was how to add a hidden field. I've since added a hidden field but for some odd reason the data is being saved to the Db. New users have a blank teacher Id. Any help would be appreciated.

Registrations controller

```
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:teacher, :teacher_id, :user_id, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:teacher, :teacher_id, :user_id, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
    enter code here
```

New.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
<div>
<% if teacher_signed_in? %>
<p>
  Sign up new student. Enter in the name, email and password that your student will use to sign in.

<%= hidden_field_tag :teacher_id, current_teacher.id %>
<% else %>
<% end %>

  <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true %>




    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: false %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to put the id in the form @bryan-dimas' answer works.

Although I'd suggest that instead of putting it in the form you set it in the controller before creating the record, that way you ensure that the user gets associated with the `Leader` that is creating the record. 
If you had it in the form, a user, with enough knowledge, could see the hidden field and change the value before submitting the form.

It would be something like:

`params.require(:user).permit(<some fields>).merge(leader_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: This worked as far as I can tell. I just edited the registrations controller, adding .merge(teacher_id: current_teacher.id)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a hidden field with the value as the `current_leaders`'s id. It will post along with the rest of the form.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :leader_id, current_leader.id %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For some reason, the leader id for new students doesn't get saved (or appears to be blank). I do have it permited in the   def sign_up_params in the registrations_controller. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: YW :). It might be because of your Model Relationships. You could show us the params that are being `POST`ed by the form or your models `teacher.rb` and `student.rb` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: This also worked: <% if teacher_signed_in? %>
<%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, :value => current_teacher.id %>
<% end %>